# [karma]: Error: Unable to resolve module [expose-loader?jQuery!jquery]

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, webpack, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to setup karma tests for typescript.

*karma.conf.js*

```
module.exports = function (config) {
    config.set({
        frameworks: ['jasmine', 'karma-typescript'],
        files: [
            {pattern: 'src/main/**/*.ts'}, // Actual code
            {pattern: 'src/test/**/*.ts'}, // Unit tests
        ],
        preprocessors: {
            'src/main/**/*.ts': ['karma-typescript', 'coverage'],
            'src/test/**/*.ts': ['karma-typescript']
        },
        reporters: ['progress', 'junit', 'coverage'],

        // the default configuration
        junitReporter: {
            ...
        },

        coverageReporter: {
            type: 'lcov',
            subdir: '.',
            dir: 'target/'
        },

        browsers: ['PhantomJS'],

        singleRun: true,
        autoWatch: true,
        logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
        colors: true,
        port: 9876
     });
 };
```

the code itself has nothing yet but:

```
import "expose-loader?jQuery!jquery";
import "expose-loader?Tether!tether";

import "../scss/main.scss";
import "bootstrap";
```

and the test :

```
it("should expose jquery to window",  () => {
    expect(window["jQuery"]).toBeDefined();
    expect(window["$"]).toBeDefined();
});
```

The problem I have is an error that karma is not able to understand expose-loader from webpack giving an error:

ERROR [karma]: Error: Unable to resolve module [expose-loader?jQuery!jquery]

could someone please shed some light on this.
Without expose-loader if I do put jquery manually everything work perfectly fine, but I want just to do it properly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem was in including actual code in "files" rather than importing the class I'm going to test. So I've made

```
{pattern: 'src/main/**/!(file with expose-loader).ts', include:'false'}
```

and excluding file that responsible for exposing global objects